# Блок с расширяющейся нижней границей

Tags: html, dom, border

Есть два блока - один во втором.

```css
.newsblock {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fa660a;
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    top: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
 
.pushstack2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #800921;
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    border: black;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsblock">
    <div class="pushstack2"></div>
</div>
```

Задача в следующем. 
Внутри блока newsblock создаются блоки pushstack2. 
Нижняя граница newsblock должна сдвигаться вниз,
когда создаваемые pushstack2 "перестают влезать"
в newsblock.

Никак не могу понять, как обеспечить сдвигание нижней границы

Comment: может быть min-height:100%;  ?

Comment: не помогло оно...

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, почему блок должен автоматически изменять высоту? У Вас `pushstack2` с позиционирован `absolute`. Я конечно может быть не прав, но `absolute`, это когда блок с этим свойством, как бы "отделяется" от страницы и спокойно "плавает" в блоке с позиционированием `relative`. Вы точно уверенны, что блок `newsblock` должен учитывать высоту и количество `pushstack2`? Мне кажется лучше использовать что-то вроде `margin-top` и `margin-bottom` незная цели и что должно получиться в итоге. Либо использовать JS: получать высоту вложенных элементов, плюсовать и устанавливать инлайн стили + отступы рассчитать. Сейчас сложно сказать что либо, но тем не менее, нужно больше инфы: как, что, почему и куда. Может быть это вообще по-другому делается. Аминь

Comment: Получилось, когда вставил в стиль pushstack margin-bottomю

Comment: Но position оставил абсолютной.  Спасибо за подсказку с margin-bottom

Comment: @Andrey1981spb не знаю зачем и почему, но вам виднее